# How to populate the EditText with the button click?

Tags: android

I want to get the values in the button to be populated in the edit text box. i.e I am creating a login page in which the pin has to entered I have given a set of numbers as buttons, when I click the button the corresponding values has to be populated in the edit text box( just like the ATM action).

I am now using:

```
 b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View paramView) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String text=(String) b1.getText();
                        pincode.setText(text);
            }
        });
```

with the above code I am getting the values populated, but I have a set of buttons, so is there any simplified way to get the values populated?
**The values currently replacing the previous one , I need multiple values in the edit text like if we press buttons 1,2,3 (values) the values in the edit text should be 123 **

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, in your activity `implements OnClickListener`

then add this listener to all your button as

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
btn2.setOnClickListener(this);
btn3.setOnClickListener(this);
```

and write onClick event as

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    Button b1 = (Button)v;
    editText.setText(editText.getText().toString()+b1.getText().toString());
}
```

and you are done :)

Comment: the code will insert the values to the edit text but it will replace the first value when a second value is typed, I need to populate all the values that I enter through the buttons

Answer (score 1):

```
onClick(View v)
{
    editText.setText(editText.getText() + v.getText());
    //plz adjust casting and spanned as per requirement
}
```

Answer (score 1):

on your button onClick you got to do this

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
yourEditText.setText(yourEditText.getText().toString+"1");
});

button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
yourEditText.setText(yourEditText.getText().toString+"2");
});
```

this way your buttons will work

Answer (score 0):

You can add text like this:

```
String a = "random text";
input = your_edit_text_box;
input.setText(a);
```

Link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html#setText%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.widget.TextView.BufferType%29

Answer (score 0):

```
Button btnNO = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
EditTExt edtText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

btnNO.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     String text= btnNo.getText();
     edtText.setText(text);

    // or direct use like, edtText.setText(btnNo.getText());
    }

});
```